# Tagging of items in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as below:

```
                Id     Type       
0              14035   A          
1              14035   B      
2              14035   C                         
3              24259   A    
4              24259   B
```

I am trying to do some classfication using pandas python where if it contains ABC/BAC/CBA permutations it is classified in category 1. if it only contains AB/BA then it is classified in category 2.

```
                Id     Classification
0              14035   Category 1                                  
3              24259   Category 2
```

I thought of using a group by and place into an arry but I am unsure about to go about it as I am still new at Python.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a possible approach using `groupby`:

```
df.groupby("Id")["Type"].apply(lambda x: "Category 1" if x.str.cat() == "ABC" else "Category 2")
```

Output:

```
Id
14035    Category 1
24259    Category 2
Name: Type, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Eventhough the previous solutions tend to work, I am concerned about the strings concatenation used.

Such string concatenation would fail to classify the IDs for the following cases:

1. If characters are concatenated in an unsorted manner, the logic behind would fail to classify the IDs. `ie: ('BAC' != 'ABC')`.
2. If the group contained extra types, for example 'ABCD', string concatenation would also fail to correctly classify the group `ie: ('ABCD' != 'ABC')`

I would rather go for a longer and safer solution as such:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Construct sample dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Id'] = ['14035', '14035', '14035', '24259', '24259', ]
df['Type'] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', ]


# Define classification logic
def classification_logic(list_of_types):
    if set(['A', 'B', 'C']) <= set(list_of_types):
        return 1
    if set(['A', 'B']) <= set(list_of_types):
        return 2
    return np.nan

# Apply to groups
df.groupby('Id').aggregate(classification_logic)
#        Type
# Id         
# 14035     1
# 24259     2
```

Comment: Hi @C.Square, I tried doing this:

testing_df = testing_df.groupby('Id',as_index=False)["Type"].aggregate (classification_logic)

to not reset the index. But it is returning me Np.Nan. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly general solution:

```
# Find which elements are present in each id
elements_in_id = df.groupby('Id').apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).sum())['Type']

categories = {"ABC" : 'Category 1', "AB" : 'Category 2'}

# Assign category if present, otherwise assign "Not Classified"
# Assume that the keys in categories contain letters sorted alphabetically
result = elements_in_id.map(lambda x: categories.get(''.join(sorted(x)), 'Not Classified'))
```

Which gives the expected output:

```
Id
14035    Category 1
24259    Category 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [@CarlesMitjans's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45101071/5741205) here is a bit optimized version:

```
In [66]: df.groupby('Id')['Type'] \
    ...:   .agg(lambda x: 'Cat 1' if 'ABC' in ''.join(x.sort_values()) else 'Cat 2') \
    ...:   .reset_index(name='Cat')
    ...:
Out[66]:
      Id    Cat
0  14035  Cat 1
1  24259  Cat 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `set` comparison to make it work irrespective of the order

```
In [976]: df.groupby("Id")["Type"].apply(
     ...:    lambda x: 'Cat 1' if set(x) == set('ABC') else
     ...:              'Cat 2' if set(x) == set('AB') else
     ...:              'Cat X')
Out[976]:
Id
14035    Cat 1
24259    Cat 2
Name: Type, dtype: object
```